# How to get the value from one class function in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This attempt is try to get the value from a function in class One which is retrieve when the function is call. Then the value [**string1**] would be passed as a parameter for class Two's method call which's within tkinter, any idea on how can it be attain

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *

class One:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Test")
        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Test", command=self.do)
        self.greet_button.pack()

    
    def do(self):
        ...some action...
         
        string1='test'
        return string1

class Two:
    def write(self, str):
     ...some action...
```

#object instantiate within tkinter

```
root = Tk()
p0 = One(root)
p0.do()
p1 = Two()
p1.write(string1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: but you don’t call the do() method.

Comment: Hi @quamrana, the thing is when im trying to call the do method, it throw 
TclError: invalid command name ".!label3", any idea

Comment: Oh, you meant: string1 = p0.do()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
##from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
##
##from tkinter import * 
##from tkinter.ttk import *

####why are you importing some and then everything?

import tkinter as tk

class Reader_Class(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, writer_class):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        master.title("Test")

        self.writer = writer_class
        self.greet_button = tk.Button(self, text="Test", command=self.do)
        self.greet_button.pack()

    
    def do(self):
        string1='test'
        self.writer.write(string1)

class Writer_Class(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
    def write(self, test):
     print(test)

root = tk.Tk()
writer = Writer_Class(root)
writer.pack()

reader = Reader_Class(root, writer)
reader.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

### Explaination:

So first of all, it isnt necessary to import stuff twice.

Second you need to pass through the interface **a reference**, therefor you need to have reference. Thats why it makes sense to **use the construktor first on the *writer_class***.

Next you give the reference as ***a parameter* to the *reader_class***.

```
reader = Reader_Class(root, writer)
```

In the reader_class you keep a **reference in the *local_scope*** by using the syntax `self.`.

```
self.writer = writer_class
```

Finally you use the reference of that class and calling a method of this class, where you can pass through a parameter of your choice.

```
self.writer.write(string1)
```

Comment: thank you, it's kinda lots of info for a newbie to digest, may i ask if i would like to have a second method in Writer_Class like write2(). It would also get a value from the Reading_Class's do method, but a different value, can it be done in similar way?

Comment: Go ahead and write `print(self.writer)` in your script. It will print the reference to that object. As long as you have a reference you will have *access* to that object. So yes, it will be pretty much the same.